# jasmine check element's visibility after click

Tags: jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine

new to Jasmine,

I have a fancy dropdown that becomes visible after clicking on a button.

I want to test that the dropdown menu becomes visible after the button is clicked.

```
describe("dropdown becomes visible", function () {

 beforeEach(function() {
    $('.dropdownButton').trigger('click');
 });

 it("should call click function", function() {    
    expect($(".dropdown-menu")is.(':visible')).toBe(true);
 });

});
```

it returns false, if I were to type those two in the console, it becomes true.

is this a typical use case for testing? I don't see many examples online.

Comment: Do those elements exist?

Comment: yes they do exist. it works when I type the same things into the console of the browser

Comment: are you using jasmine-jquery fixtures? if yes then are you providing correct html structure?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error, it should be:

```
expect($(".dropdown-menu").is(':visible')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: thanks, was a bad copy and paste. still doesn't work

Comment: Ok. I see you're using karma. Is the js file included in your karma.conf.js
?